# How to select option and post into session

Tags: php, sql, session-variables

I need to display something based on the input of a select option. The option gets written away in the session but it always gives the last value of the choices.
Hopefully someone can help me with this.
First page;

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="postchange.php" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Naam">Naam</label>  
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select id="gebruiker" name="gebruiker" placheholder="kies een gebruiker" class="form-control" required>
                        <?php

                                $conn = dbconnect();
                        // selecteer alle users waar stats == 0 en sorteert deze oplopend op ID
                                $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Status LIKE 0 ORDER BY id DESC"; 
                                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;

                        ?>
                    <option>
                        <?php
                        // Geeft het ID, voornaam + achternaam weer
                        echo "$row1[0] $row1[2] $row1[3]";
                        $test=$row1[0];
                        endwhile;
                        ?>
                    </option>
                    </select>

              </div>

        </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                      <button id="volgende" name="volgende" class="btn btn-success">volgende</button>
                  </div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>       
                            <?php 
                        $_SESSION['gebruiker']=$test;
                    ?>
```

2th page (postchange.php):
The session does echo some value here but not the selected. As mentioned previously it always gives the last value of the select option.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="#" method="post">
            <fieldset>              
<div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="soort">Configuratie item</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select id="gebruiker" name="gebruiker" placheholder="kies een gebruiker" class="form-control" required>
                            <?php

                                    $conn = dbconnect();
                                    $query = "SELECT * FROM config WHERE gebruiker='".$_SESSION['gebruiker']."';"; 
                                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                                while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;
                            ?>
                        <option>
                            <?php
                            echo "$row1[0] $row1[2] $row1[3]";?>
                        </option>
                            <?php 
                                endwhile;
                            ?>
                        </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
<?php 
                                    var_dump($gebruiker, $aanvraag, $_SESSION['userid']);

        ?>
```

Comment: I see you're setting `$test=$row1[0];` inside while loop, so it sets `$test` every time when statement comes for execution, and overwrites the value, And also what you want to achieve, should be done with `jQuery` instead of `PHP` itself.

Comment: Never worked with jQuery, do you have a link for me? Thanks for your help! @NiravMadariya

Comment: see my answer, it's workaround if you don't know jQuery and don't want to have your hands get dirty with it ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace line

`$query = "SELECT * FROM config WHERE gebruiker='".$_SESSION['gebruiker']."';";`

with,

`$query = "SELECT * FROM config WHERE gebruiker='".$_POST['gebruiker']."'";`

This should work, as it sends selected item from options.

Just a small Sample :

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <select name="bac">
        <option name="1">1</option>
        <option name="2">2</option>
        <option name="3">3</option>
        <option name="4">4</option>
        <option name="5">5</option>
        <option name="6">6</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['bac']))
        echo $_POST['bac'];
?>
```

Also, remove the below lines from your first file,

```
<?php 
   $_SESSION['gebruiker']=$test;
?>
```

**Updated**

replace :

```
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;
```

with :

```
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

and remove,

```
<?php 
    endwhile;
?>
```

Above code changes will fetch single row once.

Comment: The field on the second page stays empty, in the database only the ID of the user is mentioned. Is it possible to select only the first the characters or row1 from the array in the sql code?

Comment: updated answer, also accept it as answer, to help others in future with same problem.

Comment: Thank you! appreciate your help